# How do I use helper functions in Lumen?

Tags: laravel, lumen

```
    $credentials = app_path();
```

Results in:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]   Call to
>   undefined function App\LtClasses\app_path()

But it's listed as a helper here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-app-path

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Those are the Laravel docs, you don't have the same helpers available on Lumen, you can have a look at the helpers that the Lumen framework comes with at

[`/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/helpers.php`](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.3/src/helpers.php)

Workarounds to achive what you need here could be

```
app()->path();

app('path');

base_path('app');
```

Comment: bit of side-question then - how do I retrieve the app path from within Lumen?