# Adding helpers in lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am working Lumen for the first time and using v 6.0.

I am not able to use any of the helpers available in laravel like resource(), bcrypt() and may be anything in [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers.). Throws me

> "message":"Call to undefined function
>   App\Http\Controllers\bcrypt()"

message. I have tried adding  "laravel/helpers": "^1.2", but no luck. can someone throw some light on this. anyway I can get this running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use helper functions in Lumen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41101325/how-do-i-use-helper-functions-in-lumen)

Comment: Thanks but this doesnt really work. It doesn't have resource() helper for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lumen is a micro-framework by Laravel, this means a lot of Laravel helpers and components is not available in Lumen by default.

If you are developing a stateless application, Lumen could be very useful as it's a very fast and light weight framework which focusing on JSON APIs from version 5.2

> Only Stateless APIs
>
> Lumen 5.2 represents a shift on slimming Lumen to focus solely on
>   serving stateless, JSON APIs. As such, sessions and views are no
>   longer included with the framework. If you need access to these
>   features, you should use the full Laravel framework.

of course all Lumen features lists available in official documentation including the encryption, authentication and etc.

you may want take a look at release note and pick your choice between Lumen or Laravel: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/master